# Move ordinal files into a Folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m2J4.png)

Is there anyone who can help me automate a process of moving files into a folder according to its name?

Please see screenshot.

Query:
How to create folders according to files without the number and extension. (e.g., Alpha Wong) and move all files (Alpha Wong_1.jpg...Alpha Wong_7.jpg) inside it.

Thanks.

Comment: "Automate" - what does it mean exactly?

Comment: i tried to search for a solution involving batch files but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below, this is PowerShell:

```
$folderPath = "C:\Path\to\folder"

# Get all files in the folder
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File

# Loop through each file
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Split the file name using the underscore character
    $fileNameParts = $file.Name.Split("_")
    
    if ($fileNameParts.Count -gt 1) {
        # Extract the folder name from the file name parts
        $folderName = $fileNameParts[0]
        
        # Check if the folder exists
        $folderExists = Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $folderName) -PathType Container
        
        if ($folderExists) {
            Write-Host "Folder '$folderName' exists for file '$($file.Name)'."
        } else {
            # Create the folder
            $newFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $folderName
            New-Item -Path $newFolderPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
            Write-Host "Created folder '$folderName' for file '$($file.Name)'."
        }
        
        # Move the file to the folder
        $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $folderName
        $destinationFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $file.Name
        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destinationFile
        Write-Host "Moved file '$($file.Name)' to folder '$folderName'."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Invalid file name format: $($file.Name)."
    }
}
```

This script will create the folder if it doesn't exist and move the file into that folder. It first checks if the folder exists and if not, it creates the folder using the New-Item cmdlet. Then, it uses the Move-Item cmdlet to move the file into the newly created or existing folder.

Please ensure that you replace "C:\Path\to\folder" with the actual path to your folder.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. It works perfectly. Thank you very much sir Nuno Chaves. Now I can easily organize 10K+ files easily.

Answer (score 0):

For batch you may use the
[move command](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html) :

```
move "Some scan_*.jpg" "Some scan"
```

where `Some scan` is a sub-folder (otherwise use the full path).

Comment: I apologize. My description must be wrong. I'll edit it.